# Subview of custom UIScrollView is not getting tap events

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a custom `UIScrollView` based class `SlideShow`. It's a horizontally scrolling slide show containing a variable number of `Slide` views (derived from `UIImageView`). I have paging, scrolling, and user interaction enabled on the `SlideShow` object in IB.

I build the slide show like this:

```
@implementation SlideShow
...
// slides contains the pre-built Slide objects
// The alpha and zulu stuff is for faking infinite scroll, when the user gets to an edge.
- (void) configureSlides: (NSArray*) slides
{
    CGSize scrollSize = CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0);
    self.zuluResetMarker = 0.0;

    Slide* alphaSlide = [slides[0] copy];
    Slide* zuluSlide = [slides[slides.count - 1] copy];

    scrollSize = [self insertSlide: zuluSlide size: scrollSize];
    self.alphaSlideOffset = scrollSize.width;
    for (Slide* s in slides)
    {
        scrollSize = [self insertSlide: s size: scrollSize];
    }

    self.alphaResetMarker = scrollSize.width;
    self.zuluSlideOffset = scrollSize.width - zuluSlide.frame.size.width;
    scrollSize = [self insertSlide: alphaSlide size: scrollSize];
    self.contentSize = scrollSize;

    [self setContentOffset: CGPointMake(self.alphaSlideOffset, 0.0) animated: NO];
}

- (CGSize) insertSlide: (Slide*) slide size: (CGSize) aggregateSize
{
    [slide setOriginX: aggregateSize.width originY: 0.0];
    CGSize s = slide.frame.size;
    aggregateSize.height = s.height > aggregateSize.height ? s.height : aggregateSize.height;
    aggregateSize.width += s.width;
    [self addSubview: slide];
    return aggregateSize;
}
```

And I set a `UIGestureRecognizer` for the slide to recognize a tap, when I initialize it:

```
@implementation Slide
...
- (id) initWithImage: (UIImage*) image delegate: (id<SlideDelegate>) delegate
{
    if (self = [super initWithImage: image])
    {
        self.delegate = delegate;
        [self initialize];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) initialize
{
    [self addGestureRecognizer: [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                initWithTarget: self.delegate
                                        action: @selector(slideTapped:)]];
}
```

I verified the `initialize` method is getting called by setting a breakpoint. But the `slideTapped:` selector does not. I added `touchesBegan:withEvent:` to the `Slide` and the `SlideShow` classes, with `NSLog()` calls. The `SlideShow` object gets the call, but the `Slide` objects never do. The `Slide` object is a subview of the `SlideShow` so, according to how I read Apple's responder chain docs, I expected the `Slide` to get the touch first.

Is there something else required to get a subview to be able to respond to touch events?

Comment: Have you tried setting the 'target' on `addGestureRecognizer:initWithTarget:action:` to `self` instead of `self.delegate`?

Comment: I tried that, and it did nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that UIImageView instances defaults user interaction to `NO`. Add the following line in your init method: `self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`

In your case:

```
- (void) initialize
{
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self addGestureRecognizer: [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                            initWithTarget: self
                                    action: @selector(slideTapped:)]];
}
```